Asyncio tasks do not execute concurrently
I want to trigger a function asynchronously which gets JSON data from cli commands and then posts the data to an http endpoint.
I am new to asyncio and followed some tutorials but my code is still executing synchronously.
async def execute(project):
    nb_object = Notebooks(project)
    nb_object.get_json_data_from_cli()
    nb_object.post_data_to_http_endpoint()


async def api_handler(project):
    await execute(project)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*(api_handler(project) for project in project_scope_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

My understanding is that when my api_handler() function hits the await keyword it should return control to my main function so that the next execution in project_scope_list can begin. However, the calls are still happening one after the other.

Nothing in execute() blocks in such a way to let asyncio task-switch. If your get_json_data_from_cli or post_data_to_http_endpoint was an async call and you were doing an await for those, then you could end up task-switching between them when the first one blocks; but the thing that's actually spending time blocking on I/O needs to be built to use asyncio for you to get any benefit here.

(so if the post_data_to_http_endpoint call is where you were blocking and wanted to task-switch, f/e, then you'd want to use aiohttp and await for the HTTP call; the CLI poll is trickier, because, well, how is the user going to respond to several prompts at the same time?)

That is to say, await foo() only does a task switch when foo blocks on I/O. When you don't do any asyncio-aware I/O, you're getting no benefit.

@CharlesDuffy So get_json_data_from_cli() actually calls a binary which triggers its own API calls and returns JSON data, I don't have any control over this program to make it asynchronous. What I was trying to achieve is letting the next execution of this binary begin while I await for the results from the first one, so on and so forth. The http POST takes a a lot less time relative to this call I'm not worried if it doesn't run asynchronously but I thought asyncio should theoretically make it possible for the whole function to be awaitable while the next execution of the function begins???

I disagree with this question being closed. The linked answer does not provide an actual answer for what to do here. Doing so is awkward in a comment here.

The issue is that all of the calls in execute are synchronous and block the thread the event loop is running on. To make this asynchronous, remove the async from execute and then wrap it in asyncio.to_thread inside api_handler. Like this: await asyncio.to_thread(execute(project)).

@bmitc, ...now that the OP clarified in comments that they're calling an external process we can maybe add a better duplicate (like one demonstrating the asyncio version of subprocess), but that information wasn't present in the initial question. And insofar as with that clarification what they're doing is a use case for the asyncio-aware version of the subprocess API (with no particular need for threading), an answer that didn't take advantage of that would be suboptimal.

I don't see any need for asyncio subprocesses if get_json_data_from_cli is simply a method call in an existing library. What it does is immaterial to the caller. As written, the easiest solution is what I stated above, using asyncio.to_thread. That offloads what execute is doing to another thread (which does whatever it wants internally, such as calling a subprocess), making it asynchronous. If the user has direct control and a need to directly call the external binary, then yes, asyncio subprocesses is correct. However, it seems like not, which is what asyncio_to_thread is for.

If the Notebooks class was written by the user to try and abstract the underlying call to the external binary, then they actually have a choice. They can still use asyncio.to_thread for this class or they can use asyncio subprocesses to handle the external binary call.
